# jquery execute a request as a callback

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-callback

I would like to execute a request that is return to me in a callback,

In fact it is a system that When I click on something it displkay the conversation,

So I started to do my query, and when I click on an element it send data to the php file that return a request.

below is my jquery code :

```
 $( ".load_message" ).click(function() {
            //On marque uniquement l'id de l'expediteur et du destinataire
            // pour chercher les messages expédiés par A vers B ou inversement
            var from = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.from').text();
            var to = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.to').text();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'pages_ajax/fetch-messages.php',
                data: { from: from,  to: to},
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    // this is where we append a loading image
                    $('#message_display').empty()
                    $('#message_display').attr('style','text-align:center');
                    $('#message_display').append('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    // successful request; do something with the data
                    if(data.error==1){
                        $('#message_display').empty().removeAttr('style');

                    }
                    // if faliure
                    else if(data.error==0){
                        // failed request; give feedback to user
                        $('#message_display').empty().removeAttr('style');
                        $('#message_display').attr('class','error').empty().append('<b>Il n\'y a pas de messages à afficher.</b>');
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    // failed request; give feedback to user
                    $('#message_display').empty().removeAttr('style');
                    $('#message_display').attr('class','error').empty().append('<b>Il n\'y a pas de messages à afficher.</b>');
                }
            });
        });
```

in the php file it simply returns me a sql request

here is my php file

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("../../lib_php/librairie.php");
require_once("../../config/connexion.php");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

/**
 * Fonction qui retourne une liste de messages
 * @return int
 */
function fetchMessages() {
    $from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
    $to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);

    $query = "SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `message`, `sent`, `read`, `direction` 
    FROM `cometchat` 
    WHERE `from` = {$from} || `from` = {$to} || `to` = {$to} || `to` = {$from}";
    $data = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($data) == 0) {
        $data['error'] = 1;
        $data['sql'] = $data;
    } else {
        $data['sql'] = null;
        $data['error'] = 0;
    }

    return $data;
}

echo fetchMessages();
```

I do not know how to proceed to make a loop with that query to display all result into a div, because it is the first time that I return a query, normaly I just return some vars, that I apply. But this time I have too many data too displays.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well if you want to render the data in a callback you need to pass the callback function in. I don't see the callback function or the call to it.

Comment: this is it  success:function(data){
                    // successful request; do something with the data
                    if(data.error==1){
                        $('#message_display').empty().removeAttr('style');

                    }
                    // if faliure
                    else if(data.error==0){
                        // failed request; give feedback to user
                        $('#message_display').empty().removeAttr('style');

Comment: Oh. I thought you meant a callback function to render the data.

Comment: oh I just want to execute the query and to display it into a div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fetchMessages() {
    $from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
    $to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);

    $query = "SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `message`, `sent`, `read`, `direction` 
    FROM `cometchat` 
    WHERE `from` = {$from} OR `from` = {$to} OR `to` = {$to} OR `to` = {$from}";

    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));

    $data = array();
    if (!sizeof($results)) {
        $data['error'] = 1;
        $data['sql'] = $query;
    } else {
        $data['sql'] = null;
        $data['error'] = 0;
        $data['results'] = $results;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

usage:

```
$data = fetchMessages();
if ($data['error']) {
    // show error
}
else
{
    foreach ($data['results'] as $result) {
        // debug
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: as a side note, `mysql_query` etc... are depreciated. use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: @user2506760 what do you mean?

Comment: I just want do execute that query  and to display the result into an Iframe

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: DO NOT USE MYSQL_*, it is deprecated due to security concerns.
Step 2: Use prepared statements.

I've rewritten your php here:

```
function fetchMessages() {
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];

    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `message`, `sent`, `read`, `direction` 
    FROM `cometchat` 
    WHERE `from` = ? || `from` = ? || `to` = ? || `to` = ?");
    $query->bind_param('ssss' $from, $to, $to, $from);
    $result=$query->execute();
    $query->data_bind($id, $rfrom, $rto, $message, $sent, $read, $direction);

    $data=""; //initialize the HTML you want in here, any sort of header for the data
    while ($query->fetch()){
      $data=$data.$id." ".$rfrom." ".$rto." ".$message." ".$sent." ".$read." ".$direction."<br/> //or whatever html formatting you want to do
    }
    $data=$data."<br/>" //or whatever tailing html you want to add to the data

    return $data;
}
echo  fetchMessages()
```

Comment: thank you but How can I execute the query to be display asyncrhon, do you think it may be better to use an iframe ?

Comment: @user2506760 what do you mean? the ajax request will run asynchronously and wait for the server to give it input.  I guess another way around would be to use .load() on the div, I'm not sure what you mean by asynchron.  Can you describe what results you're looking for without using technical terms?